# Easy Rotator issue with .load jQuery method

Tags: jquery, html

I am having some issues with Easy Rotator(loads images and display them inside a slide show). The script works perfectly if I don't use the jquery .load method to load a .html file that contains the code to be loaded.The code for the html file is as follows. Thanks for your time!

```
<!-- Begin DWUser_EasyRotator -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://c520866.r66.cf2.rackcdn.com/1/js/easy_rotator.min.js"></script>
<div class="dwuserEasyRotator" style="width: 550px; height: 360px; position:relative; text-align: left;" data-erConfig="{autoplayEnabled:false, lpp:'102-105-108-101-58-47-47-47-67-58-47-85-115-101-114-115-47-67-97-109-114-105-110-47-68-111-99-117-109-101-110-116-115-47-69-97-115-121-82-111-116-97-116-111-114-80-114-101-118-105-101-119-47-112-114-101-118-105-101-119-95-115-119-102-115-47'}" data-erName="Our Brands">
<div data-ertype="content" style="display: none;"><ul data-erlabel="Main Category">
<li>
<img class="main" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_ChickenCoating.jpg" />
<img class="thumb" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_ChickenCoating.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
<img class="main" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_ChipFlixcanisters1.jpg" />
<img class="thumb" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_ChipFlixcanisters1.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
<img class="main" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_NatureValley.jpg" />
<img class="thumb" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_NatureValley.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
<img class="main" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_Tortillas.jpg" />
<img class="thumb" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_Tortillas.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
<img class="main" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_UrbanClassics1.jpg" />
<img class="thumb" src="imgs/slideshow/Maxxim_UrbanClassics1.jpg" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-ertype="layout" data-ertemplateName="NONE" style="">      
<div class="erimgMain" style="position: absolute; left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:70px;" data-erConfig="{___numTiles:3, scaleMode:'fillArea', imgType:'main', __loopNextButton:false, arrowButtonMode:'rollover'}">
        <div class="erimgMain_slides" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0; bottom:0; right:0px;">
            <div class="erimgMain_slide">
                <div class="erimgMain_img" style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;"></div>
                <div class="" style="background: #000; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.85); position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; padding: 5px; color: #FFF; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;">
                    <p class="erimgMain_title" style="padding: 0; margin: 0 0 3px 0; font-weight: bold;"></p>
                    <p class="erimgMain_desc" style="padding: 0 0 10px 0; margin: 0;"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="erimgMain_arrowLeft" style="position:absolute; left: 10px; top: 50%; margin-top: -15px;" data-erConfig="{image:'circleSmall', image2:'circleSmall'}"></div>
        <div class="erimgMain_arrowRight" style="position:absolute; right: 10px; top: 50%; margin-top: -15px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="erimgMain rotatorTileNav" style="position: absolute; left:0;right:0;bottom:0;height:80px;" data-erConfig="{numTiles:-1, scaleMode:'fillArea', imgType:'thumb', loopNextButton:false, arrowButtonMode:'rollover', __slideLinkEvent:'rollover'}">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 10px; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: #FFF;"></div>
        <div class="erimgMain_slides" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0; bottom:0; right:0px;">
            <div class="erimgMain_slide">
                <div class="erimgMain_img" style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 10px; bottom: 0; margin: 2px 1px;"></div>
                <!-- <div class="" style="background: #555; position: absolute; left: 1px; right: 1px; top: 10px; bottom: 0; padding: 5px; color: #FFF; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">
                    <p class="erimgMain_title" style="padding: 5px; margin: 0 0 3px 0; font-weight: bold;"></p>
                </div> -->
                <div class="selectionArrow visibleWhenSelected" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; margin-left: -10px; width: 20px; height: 10px; background-image: url('http://easyrotator.s3.amazonaws.com/1/i/rotator/FFF_arrow10_export.png');"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="erimgMain_arrowLeft" style="position:absolute; left: 60px; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px;" data-erConfig="{image:'circleSmall', image2:'circleSmall'}"></div>
        <div class="erimgMain_arrowRight" style="position:absolute; right: 60px; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px;"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="erabout erFixCSS3" style="color: #FFF; text-align: left; background: #000; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.93); border: 2px solid #FFF; padding: 20px; font: normal 11px/14px Verdana,_sans; width: 300px; border-radius: 10px; display:none;">
        This <a style="color:#FFF;" href="http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/" target="_blank">jQuery slider</a> was created with the free <a style="color:#FFF;" href="http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/" target="_blank">EasyRotator</a> software from DWUser.com.
        <br /><br />
        Need a powerful <a style="color:#FFF;" href="http://www.dwuser.com/flashslideshow/" target="_blank">Flash slideshow</a> creator with built-in iPhone/iPad/Android support?  EasyRotator is supported by the <a style="color:#FFF;" href="http://www.dwuser.com/flashslideshow/" target="_blank">XML Flash Slideshow v4 Software</a>.
        <br /><br />
        <a style="color:#FFF;" href="#" class="erabout_ok">OK</a>   
    </div>
    <noscript>
        Rotator powered by <a href="http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/">EasyRotator</a>, a free and easy <a href="http://www.dwuser.com/easyrotator/">jQuery slider</a> builder from DWUser.com.  Please enable JavaScript to view. 
    </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">/*Avoid IE gzip bug*/(function(b,c,d){try{if(!b[d]){b[d]="temp";var a=c.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.src="http://easyrotator.s3.amazonaws.com/1/js/nozip/easy_rotator.min.js";c.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)}}catch(e){alert("EasyRotator fail; contact support.")}})(window,document,"er_$144");</script>
</div>
```

I FOUND THE PROBLEM , the following code segment:
data-erConfig="{autoplayEnabled:false

Should be changed to data-erConfig="{autoplayEnabled:true

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to make sense of what is going wrong here as the code is quite compressed. Might I suggest adding a style sheet to remove the 'style' attributes on your html elements.

As I said, I am unsure of the problem, but I do however have a potential fix. The jQuery .load method is very unreliable, this is admitted by jQuery themselves. Consequently, I have come up with a workaround for all of my sites.

Using javascript I create an image, and then detect whether the image is fully loaded using

```
image.complete
```

and

```
image.height
```

If 'height' or 'complete' resolve to false then I know it has not finished loading.

I would advise staying away from plugins and write them yourself. This will give you a lot more control over how the script works. In addition it will make it much easier for you to debug in cases like this.

Use code such as the following to detect whether an image has loaded:

```
// Add any global images that you would like to preload
var images = new Array('http://example.com/images/logo.png');
this.image = new Array();

    function preload(){
        // Any images that are not in the above array but are present on the page, add them
        $('img').each(function(){
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            if(src!=''&&typeof src!='undefined'&&images.indexOf(src)==-1){
                images.push(src);
            }
        });
        // Loop through the array and create an 'image' for each image src
        for(var i=0; i <images.length;) {
            this.image[i] = new Image();
            this.image[i].src = images[i];
            this.image.onload=i++;
        }
        loaded();
    }

    function loaded(){
        // Presume the images are loaded by setting the flag to true
        var i,flag=true;
        // Loop through all of the images
        for(i=0;i<this.image.length;i++){
            // If an image has not completely loaded then set the flag to false
            if(!this.image[i].complete||!this.image[i].height){     
                flag=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag){
            // If the flag is true then all the images are loaded so run the initialize function
            initialize();
        }else{
            // If the images are not loaded then run the function again in 0.1 seconds
            setTimeout("loaded()", 100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice however the client has requested that this plugin be used.

Comment: Well, that is up to them. The above may still help you to determine the states of the images.